# What is the difference Focus mode and AF-Area mode?

Tags: nikon, focus, nikon-d5100

I am using Nikon D5100. To shoot a subject which is:

1. Stationary:

   - we can set AF-area mode to Single Point AF
   - we can set Focus mode to AF-S
2. Moving:

   - we can set AF-area mode to Dynamic-Area AF
   - we can set Focus mode to AF-C
3. Or we can set both AF-area and Focus mode to Auto-area AF and AF-A

These settings for AF-area mode and Focus mode look similar to me. I am not able to make out a difference between these two. What if the camera only has AF-area mode and no Focus mode?

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer: Focus mode is how the camera focus while the AF-area is where the camera focus.**

Focus modes

- AF-S/One Shot AF - Find focus only once while the release button is half-pressed
- AF-C/AI Servo AF - Find focus until the release button is fully pressed or released
- AF-A/AI Focus AF - Let the camera decide if it should use AF-S or AF-C
- MF - The photographer decide the focus manually

AF Area

- Single point - Focus mainly on the selected point
- Dynamic-Area - Focus on the selected point and the area around it in case of movement
- Auto-area - Camera decide where it should focus on
- 3D-tracking - A better tracking of objects in motion. (Not all cameras have this mode)

For a bit more detailed answer on AF Area you could check the answer from the question: [When to use a particular auto-focus mode](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/3698/21273)

Comment: Auto Area AF seems to imply face detection according to [Nikon's materials](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Learn-And-Explore/Article/ftlzi4po/af-area-modes.html)

Comment: There is no face detection in D5100 in the through-the-lens mode (the OP uses that for focusing). Face detection is only available in LiveView (and I have not yet seen any camera actually that does face detection through the lens).

Answer (score 3):

In AF-S, you can use

- Single-point AF (you select a fixed focus point)
- Auto-area AF (camera selects focus point automatically)

When focus is acquired, there is no more focus tracking.

In AF-C and AF-A, you have

- Single-point AF (you select a fixed focus point)
- Dynamic-area AF (you select a fixed focus point, camera tries to stay in focus by using nearby focusing points as well)
- 3D-tracking (you select the subject by a focus point, camera tries to track that subject)
- Auto-area AF (camera selects focus point automatically)

The camera is adjusting focus as the subject or your camera moves.

Note that AF-A can switch to AF-S **or** AF-C when in Single-point AF or in Auto-area AF!

So the total combinations are:

- 2 in AF-S
- 4 in AF-C
- 4 in AF-A with the flavor that it can select AF-S or AF-C in two modes.

I hope this answer your question.

For more information, see the D5100's User Manual page 32 for TTL focus, page 44 for LiveView focus.